# How to use a view to span two tables that are identical

Tags: sql-server, view, table

We have table A that receives data from our shop floor and we currently have it so that the data is moved from table A to table B after 5 years. I want to streamline this but need help creating a view. I can change the stored procedure to move the data after one month, but need to be able to point to a view with the combined data of table A and B. I tried the below but get the following error: "Column name 'PARTNOAUX' in view or function 'Table_Full_' is specified more than once."

```
CREATE VIEW Table_Full AS
SELECT *
FROM [A].[dbo].[AUX] AS S
Inner Join [B].[dbo].[AUX]AS T
ON S.DATETIMEAUX=T.DATETIMEAUX;
```

Comment: I've successfully used [partitioned view](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190019%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) in this scenario.

Comment: Don't use `SELECT *`. Your problem would have been obvious if you'd listed out your columns individually.

Answer (score 10):

You'll need to use a `union` instead. If your data is indeed distinct, use a `union all` for better performance -- the step to eliminate duplicates is eliminated.

```
create view table_full as
select *
from [A].[dbo].[AUX]
union all
select *
from [B].[dbo].[AUX];
```